# Подсказки для ячеек в таблице HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть сайтик [ссылка](http://test.florans.md/zakaz.html) нужно сделать подсказку (картинка) ячеек 
 примерно как на этом [сайте](http://xn--j1agcjjg.xn--p1ai/internet-zakaz2)

я пробовал дефолтный tooltip bootstrap вставить не получается

подкиньте идею как реализовать

Comment: самое простое: абсолютно спозиционировать каждую картинку относительно нужной ячейки, скрыть их все, а по ховеру на ячейке показывать соответствующую картинку

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 1):

Всё-таки решил с помощью bootstrap добавил в js файл кусок кода

```js
$('.td-toogle tr').tooltip({
    animated: 'fade',
    placement: 'right',
    html: true
});
```

и в яйчейке прописал

```html
title="<img src='img/products/product.jpg' />"
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width:300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.item-title{
  flex-grow:1;
}
.item:hover > .item-img{
  display:block;
}
.item-img{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top:-1px;
}
.item-img img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
  <div class='item-title'>
    Название
  </div>
  <div class='item-count'>
    4
  </div>
  <div class='item-img'>
    <img src=''>
  </div>
</div>
```